# Absolute positioned links with z-index in IE8 are not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, z-index, absolute

I'm currently developing this site: http://shiralea.littlegiantdev.co.nz/ but in IE8 the links in the top menu don't detect any mouse hover (with jQuery). I cannot figure out why! >:(

They are position:absolute, display:block and z-index:10.

Here's my stylesheet: http://shiralea.littlegiantdev.co.nz/wp-content/themes/shiralea/css/main.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to add an image to the anchor tag. I added a 1x1 transparent png and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem and adding an image to the empty a link that had a width and height worked. No jquery involved.